# How to input multiple variables of different type in one line? For example -> string string int string int

Tags: java, input

Using a hash table implemented in Java and I need to take 5 input values, 3 of which are String and 2 are Integers. The user must be able to write all input values IN ONE LINE. I tried many different ways mostly using arrays and i couldn't find the right answer online. If anyone could help provide a sample code or idea i would be thankful :)

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number of people:");
        int n = input1.nextInt();

        HTable table = new HTable(100);

        String a[] = new String[5];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            a = input.nextLine().split(" ");
            table.Insert(a[0], a[1], Integer.parseInt(a[2]), a[3], Integer.parseInt(a[4]));
        }
```

This is the most recent example i tried but it keeps taking inputs and the FOR() loop doesn't seem to end.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you add a code example with what you've already tried?

Comment: I added a code example :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can try like this :

```
public class Name{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println( "Enter Your Input ");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) 
    { 
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println(" Your Value (Int) : " + scanner.nextInt());
        } else if (scanner.hasNextFloat()) {
            System.out.println(" Your Value (Float) " + scanner.nextFloat());
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println( " String Value(String) " + scanner.next());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What does .hasNext() do and how is it different to Next() ?

Comment: hasNext() will return true if iteration has more values and Next() will return the next element.